# Azure Command not working in PowerShell module with Sitecore 9.3

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to upload a CSV to Blob. Using `Sitecore 9.3`.

Sitecore `PowerShell` module is throwing the below error:

```
New-AzStorageContext : The term 'New-AzStorageContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Any pre-requisites before running the Azure command or any module needs to be installed?

Comment: Can you try running this command in PowerShell `Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber` and then check?

Comment: It does not work from the Sitecore powershell module.  Both are different, the PSE in sitecore and powershell for windows. The PSE is not allowing the Azure cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

As a pre-requisite you have to install [Az.Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-8.3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-3.0.0) module providing Storage service cmdlets to manage blobs, queues, tables and files in MS Azure storage accounts.

Go to the *Modules* menu item and search for *"Az.Storage"* in the module gallery, then click on the `Az.Storage` module in the found list and import this module.

You call some methods from the `Az.Storage` module and get the error clearly stating that some of your commands are not recognised, so try to install the `Az.Storage` module.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install the `Az.Storage` with the follow command:

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Storage
```